# Flutter webview failed to fit webpage with screen

Tags: flutter, webview

i'm using webview_flutter: ^0.3.14+1.

Webview can't load web page `https://m.bilibili.com/video/av57346110.html` correctly. [The web page is oversized](https://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/1615625-c76c8b68aa8c311f.png?imageMogr2/auto-orient/strip%7CimageView2/2/w/1240)

But if I open it with chrome, the web page fits screen [correctly](https://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/1615625-9c52bbdcc8460abb.png?imageMogr2/auto-orient/strip%7CimageView2/2/w/1240).

And I don't understand the difference between web browser and flutter webview.

Here's minimal codes to reproduce:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: "https://m.bilibili.com/video/av57346110.html",
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              print("Loading... ${request.url}");
              if(request.url.startsWith("http")) {
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              } else {
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I implement this with same plugin 'webview_flutter' and it is working just fine.

Here is my code

```
WebView(
   initialUrl: 'https://m.bilibili.com/video/av57346110.html',
   javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
   allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
)
```

[image: here is screenshot, I wrap up this web view in aspect ratio]